# Copy from one file to another in haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to copy all the conetnts of one file to another in haskell . Plz help me to do it in winhugs. Is there any built in function to do so?

Otherwise i need a function to do it which take in input both file names

Answer (score 2):

Try [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=copyfile)

```
>import System.Directory(copyFile)
>:t copyFile
copyFile :: FilePath -> FilePath -> IO ()
```